# VLCKit with calls to libvlc

Tags: macos, vlc, libvlc

I'm using VLCKit which works nicely but I need to do some calls to the underlying libvlc as well. The VLCKit framework however does not contain the headers I need to do those calls.

I've googled extensively and can't find any mention of hybrid projects. Building vlc on OS X itself also didn't work out of the box. Any pointers how to set this up?

Comment: which calls do you need? we can easily extend the ObjC API if there is stuff missing, but you shouldn't cross the border and access libvlc directly...

Comment: That explains! What I need is to pass a VLC played video (RTSP) to Syphon and for that I need to get my hands on the raw data going through VLC. So I thought I'd need either to do something with libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject or more likely with libvlc_video_set_callbacks. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Specifically: we would like access to the opengl context and texture that VLC draws into the NSView.

Comment: The texture is not exposed through libvlc. All you could get is the CALayer used to setup the OpenGL context we are drawing into.

Comment: Ok. How would I get that from VLCKit (or from libvlc)?

Comment: There is an informal API protocol implemented in vout_ios2.m (within vlc.git) which should offer some guidance. This is currently no supported behaviour. Alternatively, you can try to make our caopengllayer video output work on iOS, which is directly drawing to a CALayer without the need for a wrapper view. However, it is tested on the Mac only so far, so it may contain calls which are unavailable on iOS.